# Editing user Manager Quota Services on Cpanel

Tags: email, cpanel

I have an issue with my domain mailbox. After i edited user manager email and FTP services quota for user on cpanel all my emails on inbox has deleted and it shows zero email for trash, inbox, sent and etc..
is there a way to restore them?

i tried to set the edits back as it was (enabled for email and disabled for FTP as in the image below) but it didn't help

[image]